# Integer version of c++ standard library midpoint

Tags: c++, integer

I was extremely annoyed by the lengthy, edge-case-galore explanation of integer version of C++ standard library mindpoint implementation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBtAGxBh-XI), so I made my own simple 2's complement version. I present it for your judgement.

The general idea is to carry out `a + (b-a)/2` in a wider signed integer that won't ever overflow.
Say a and b are N bit integers. Consider them as imaginary signed (2's complement) N+1 bit integers. The obvious magic of 2's complement is that we can carry out addition/subtraction as usual, so first we obtain the lower N bits of the hypothetical N+1 bit difference,

```
Unsigned diff = Unsigned(b) - Unsigned(a);
```

working with unsigned type to avoid signed overflow UB. We don't really have the +1 bit, so just imagine sign extension also happens. We only care about lower N bits anyway since we know the final half difference has to fit there. Problem is - we can't do division in this straightforward way, so we have to branch, based on the sign of the final result.

- If N+1 bit difference was negative (highest/sign bit set), we jump through hoops:
  Negate/abs (2's complement approved as subtraction 0-diff).
  `Unsigned negative_2x = -diff;` 
  Divide (it works cause sign bit is now guaranteed 0).
  `negative_2x /= 2;`
  Now we can fit this halved difference back into our original N bit signed int, so we convert it back and negate to restore the original sign.
  `Integer negative = -Integer(negative_2x);` 
  Converting first is important to avoid signed overflow UB again. If original Integer was unsigned this still works, since the wrapping behavior is consistent with 2's complement.
- Otherwise if difference was positive, it fully fit in N bits unsigned, and half of it should fit in signed, no hoops:
  `Integer positive = diff / 2;`

The actual branch looks like this to encourage conditional move, not that compilers care...

```
return a + (b < a ? negative : positive);
```

The code by itself with a primitive/stand-in function signature, for the purposes of copying into an IDE and compiling:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Integer, typename Unsigned = std::make_unsigned_t<Integer>>
Integer midpoint(Integer a, Integer b)
{
    Unsigned diff = Unsigned(b) - Unsigned(a);

    Unsigned negative_2x = -diff;
    negative_2x /= 2;
    Integer negative = -Integer(negative_2x);

    Integer positive = diff / 2;

    return a + (b < a ? negative : positive);
}
```

Also available [here](https://git.sr.ht/%7Enamark/libsimple_support/tree/68b0f2380c358059b39ef0891d33243a0b3e347e/source/simple/support/algorithm.hpp#L344), passes all the libstdc++ and libc++ unit tests for integers.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We can only review code that is included in the question. While we can use repositories for reference, there just isn't enough code in the question to review and that makes the question off-topic. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Please note that if the code isn't working as expected that also makes the question off-topic.

Comment: That's exactly what he does for integers in the video. Just written slightly different but the point is the same. You also need to make that no branches were generated in compilation like he did.

Comment: @ALX23z Obviously the point would be the same, it's an implementation of the same function, but it is in no way exactly the same, it's the difference between "but what if, but what if, but what if" type of code, and an elegant solution. It generates shorter branch-less assemebly than the current standard implementation.

Comment: No idea why this was closed, I wrote the code, and it is present in its entirety in the question. I just added more elaborate comments on it.
The context of the code is c++ standard library midpoint, the integer part. That should tell you everything you want to know, if not - you should watch that video I linked.

Comment: @pacmaninbw There are 7 lines, and I didn't know there is a limit. I expect the usual criticisms on readability - variables could be named differently, expression written down differently, or could be that entirely different set of primitives could be chosen to express the same thing (for instance the neg-div-neg sequence is actually `a - (a-b)/2`, where `a=0, b=diff`, and I have a function that does that called `halfwayback`, but I wasn't able to utilize it). Also c++ specific stuff, standard compliance, portability, weird edge cases perhaps, codegen etc.

Comment: see, those 7 lines in that post don't look like the 7 lines in your IDE of choice. We really don't want you to sprinkle the code under review in between an extensive explanation of what the code does. Instead we want to see the code and an explanation for it. Taking a look at other questions on the site (that have not been closed) hopefully gives you an idea how this community prefers questions. I'd also avoid "wrong" in the question title, if only because people could easily get the wrong idea about what you're actually asking for...

Comment: @Vogel612 I don't understand the implication. If you understand what I've presented tell me how to improve it. Are you saying I should just copy those 7 lines and paste them at the end, after the explanations? I wouldn't recommend copying it into an IDE from here, if you want to run it or experiment with it I provided you a link to my code repository, you can check it out, open the file, jump to the line, `make test` if you will, or just copy from there. Here I didn't want to draw attention towards the function signature or the static assertions, as they are a bit out of context.

Comment: Yes, we want to see the full code, we want function signatures, we want context. If you think each line needs a separate explanation, put it in a code comment. And definitely don't put "what's wrong" in the title of your question. And links can carry additional information that is not necessary but we cannot consider them a legitimate part of your question. We cannot know if the link is dead or provides different information by tomorrow...

Comment: @slepic You misunderstand, the link to code I provided is not the context, it's just for convenience. The context is c++ standard library midpoint. I edited to clarify. Again I don't want you reviewing the signature, it is not the same as standard's for my own purposes, that are out of context.
I put the explanations in as code comments initially but it looked horrible, so I thought why not make them formatted? what's the difference?

Comment: Somebody here does not understand, that's for sure. Look, you can keep your own truth and get rejected by the community or you accept the community truth and post it the way the community wants it. Easy as that.

Comment: @slepic If you ask me, understanding is between people, not within a person, one person can't not understand, two people might understand or not understand each other, so I did not mean to insult you, or question your beliefs, by telling you that you misunderstood the context. I, myself, don't understand what you want from me, and your are not answering my questions directly. I met all of the criteria, the code is there in its entirety, the context is clarified. If you want, I can copy and paste the full standard implementation, or maybe just the signature from it, but that's just noise IMHO.

Comment: "the code is there in its entirety" that's disputable. If I cut a picture into pieces and toss those pieces into a cup of tea, then I give you the tea and say "nice picture, huh?" even if you were an arts expert, you wouldn't be very confident answering that one, would you? We want a specification and its implementation - the code, possibly decorated with some explanatory comments. Rather than an essay with fragments of code in it.

Comment: @slepic Comparing code to a picture is curious. I, for one, do not appreciate monolithic code that is impossible to subdivide into meaningful pieces. I wanted to clearly explain the logic behind it, because I think it is important. I expect I would have to do it in the comments, if I didn't do it in the question. The specification is c++ standard library midpoint, the integer part. Implementation is presented in its entirety. Interface is defined by the standard and can be put in code in various ways. Wheat exactly do you want changed? Just a copy of the code after the explanations?

Comment: Probably. Yes. Including any asserts, called functions, used namespaces and included headers. Some edge test cases won't hurt either. If we can just copy and compile the thing, you're much more likely to get feedback.

Comment: @slepic I was referring to the exact code presented, nothing extra, and issue is not that I'm not getting enough feedback, it is that the question was closed for no specific reason. In c++ the function signature can be just as complex as the implementation, that's why I deliberately avoided it, my focus is on the implementation. Nevertheless I've added some compilable code, bracing for signature criticism. I haven't written any tests myself, I used existing ones, and to include those would be against the rules. Also the whole point of my approach is to leave no edge cases to conciser.

Comment: Seems good enough now. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @slepic Thank you for your comments, the question has been reopened.

Comment: Since the question is good now, might as well remove the downvotes!

Answer (score 4):

## Naming things

The variable names are not very clear. I assume the `_2x` stands for "2's complement" instead for "times 2", but for someone who doesn't know the context, it will be hard to follow. I'm not sure what the best way to name them is though, but as shown below you can avoid the issue altogether.

## Don't use a template parameter for a derived type

If you make `Unsigned` a template parameter, it means someone can override it to something nonsensical. If you want to have a named type that is a derivative of another type, use `using` inside the function body:

```
template<typename Integer>
Integer midpoint(Integer a, Integer b)
{
    using Unsigned = std::make_unsigned_t<Integer>;
    ...
}
```

## Simplifying the code

Most of the temporary variables can be removed. I would keep the variable `diff`, as it is the most important one where the casts are essential, and since it is used twice:

```
template<typename Integer>
Integer midpoint(Integer a, Integer b)
{
    using Unsigned = std::make_unsigned_t<Integer>;
    Unsigned diff = Unsigned(b) - Unsigned(a);
    return a + (b < a ? -Integer(Unsigned(-diff) / 2) : Integer(diff / 2));
}
```

The return expression is still reasonably short, and I don't think any information was lost. Adding some comments explaining why the casts are necessary would be helpful though.

Comment: Hm now I wonder now if it should be `-Integer(-diff / 2)` or not, as you mentioned that this might be UB otherwise, but would it still be UB with C++20's mandatory two's complement signed integers?

Comment: I have Unsigned as template parameter to use the function for types other than the fundamental integers, without specializing std::make_unsigned_t, but that is out of context here, I wanted to discuss the implementation only, I was "forced" to include the signature. In context of standard spec of midpoint, I can criticize your signature as well to no end.

Comment: The `_2x` does indeed mean 2 times, indicating that we are dealing with a number that is twice the range of our original (+1 bit), and only after properly halfing it can we assign it back to the original type. One should be familiar with 2's compliment to understand this code yes, but I think that's better than consider numerous edge cases. You might have not concidered char or short, and promotion rules, since you code is failing some test cases. You can check out the repo I linked, modify the midpoint there and run `make test` see the details.

Comment: It is possible that a single cast can be eliminated thanks to C++20's two's complement, but there are a lot more casts happening there, mainly to combat pesky promotion. I wonder what things might look like with something like safe_numerics library employed here, and what the codegen would be.

Comment: I can only review the code you show here, so in that context the `Unsigned` template parameter is avoidable. If you need it in your code, then of course you should keep using it. If you want to be safe on platforms that do not have two's complement arithmetic, then still I would avoid the temporary variables, and write: `return a + (b < a ? -Integer(-diff / 2) : Integer(diff / 2))`.

Comment: The issue is not just signed overflow, it is promotion, which applies to all arithmetic, including unary minus, and prevents the modulo arithmetic that this method relies on. Your code still doesn't pass the tests, you probably need one or two more casts in your one-liner. Even if correct I think the code is less readable that way. That said nobody would even recognize what I wrote as code so who am I to judge.

Comment: It's interesting that it doesn't pass the tests. What compiler and CPU architecture are you using? Clang and GCC produce the same assembly for your version as for mine.

Comment: I tried with gcc on x86_64, are you sure the assembly is the same for short and char? For example one of the failing cases looks like this `midpoint(limits::max(), limits::min()) == T( 0)` where `T` is singed char/short and `limits` is `std::numeric_limits<T>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116816/discussion-between-g-sliepen-and-namark).